# MS Access -- quick filter on a subform, then pass the filter to a report

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter, report, subform

I have a form (frmDocumentList) with a subform(frmDocumentDatasheet) and a print button which opens a report(rptDocumentList).

All i want to do is use the "quick filter function" (sort&filter-ribbon) on the subform. And then pass the filtered data to the report.

At the moment the report takes all of the data.

I think this is a simple problem but it is not possible for me atm to solve it. I have experience with vba. 
Hopefully someone can help me. 
-sorry for my bad english-

Here is the vba i tried:

```
 Private Sub Command17_Click()

If Not IsNull(Me.Form![Document Datasheet].[Filter]) Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "RptDocumentList", A_PREVIEW, , Me.Form![Document Datasheet].Filter
Else
    MsgBox "Apply a filter to the form first"
End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that the quick filter i used on the subform doesn't apply on the report.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some VBA?  What problems are you having, precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your command button is on the main form, then you want a different filter:  you want the filter that is on the sub-form.  Something like:

```
Option Explicit  ' <- be sure this is at top of module
                 ' ...and run Debug>Compile so it can perform its check

'' And on your button click event:
Private Sub Command17_Click()
    Dim strFilter as String
    strFilter = Me.Form![Document Datasheet].[Filter]
    Debug.Print strFilter
    If strFilter <> "" Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "RptDocumentList", A_PREVIEW, , strFilter
    Else
        MsgBox "Apply a filter to the form first"
    End If
End Sub
```

Just reference the *name* of the subform -- that is, its control name as seen on the main form.  More [here](http://www.allenbrowne.com/casu-04.html).

Using a variable like `strFilter` will hopefully give you a bit more control so you can see what is (or is not) happening.

The `Debug.Print` command causes your filter string appear in the Immediate window.  If you are unfamiliar with this, I suggest you do a bit of research as it will undoubtedly help you.  For one thing, you can post the output -- maybe your string is somehow the problem.

You will notice my code tests for an empty string (`""`).  Possibly your filter is an empty string and the `IsNull()` test is not helping you to detect that.

Comment: My command button is on the main form, that's right.

so the name of my subform is: frmDocumentDatasheet

"If Not IsNull(Me.Form!frmDocumentDatasheet.Filter) Then"

But now i get a error that it cant find the field frmDocumentDatasheet...

Comment: If Not IsNull(Forms.frmDocumentList.frmDocumentDatasheet.Form) Then ?? this produces the next error: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Don't use the name you gave the form when you made it, the name you see in the Navigation Panel .  When you made it a subform, it became a control in the main form.  That control has a name, found as a property -- that is what you must use.  The link I provided should make this clear.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but somehow it still doesnt work.. I'm very thankful that you invest the time in me. I updated the vba box in my question. Can you have another look at it?
Does the filter- field/property create itself?